# What is the best passing to functions - variables or arrays/objects?

Tags: php, function

What is the best practice regarding passing data to functions - variables, or arrays(objects).

For example, I need user info for most functions. Should I pass full user object with all information, or just only what I need (always username, sometimes id, seldom other user info)

```
function do_something($data, $user) // $user is object
```

or

```
function do_something($data, $user_name, $user_id) // only variables
```

What is the best practice for this case?

Comment: Too broad/general to have a best practice. There are many cases where one or the other is the better decision.

Comment: @Shakti Singh: That's a joke, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a developer when you start out coding, you have a certain number of things a function will require in order for it to work, some may be optional too, so you set out to create a method signature similar to the one below.

```
function do_something($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4 = false, $var5 = '')  {

//process business logic here

}
```

Now, say you implement  and get more feedback on features and other improvements. If the features or improvements suggested require you to change the method signature to incorporate new variables and you use default values, you are in a bit of a spot.

So what is the best way to avoid such situations? In my opinion, if you use a function which accepts variables, it could easily scale to accept more parameters without breaking anything by accepting an array as a single parameter. The array would have to be built up either internally in the code somewhere or externally through the user.

So you could rewrite the above logic as below:

```
function do_something($args = array()) {

$myvar = (array_key_exists('mykey', $args)) ? $args['mykey'] : get_default_value('mykey');

//process business logic here

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no better practice for *all* scenarios. Use either one depending on the purpose of your function:

- You may pass the values of individual object properties if your function doesn't care about the object.
- You should pass the object if your function is going to manipulate the object in some way, either by directly modifying its properties or by calling its methods.