# When designing a function do you pass explict values or an object with those values?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

This is just a simple design question ... who's answer might be more opinion or preference, or 'it depends' but I'll ask it anyways.

If I need to create a function that takes some values but I have an object contains those values do you pass the full object or the values only.

such as:

```
private void myFunction (int obj.a, double obj.b, bool obj.c , Object subObj)
```

or

```
private void myFunction (Object obj)
```

I'm looking at some code I wrote and I was not consistent with how I did this.  And now I want to clean up the code but these differences is making it more work.

Are there some industry 'rules of thumbs' that this relates to (KISS,DRY,SOLID)?

Is there perhaps some rules or guide lines you follow?

Is there some other method I'm over looking?

Thanks.

p.s. I'm guess the object could be IObject, which might be better (??) but I don't think that changes the overall question.

Comment: There's a very very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905468/what-is-the-best-passing-to-functions-variables-or-arrays-objects) but the accepted answer doesn't ring well with general OO practices, as it's PHP-specific.

Answer (score 4):

While the answer may very well vary from programmer to programmer, people have come up with rules of thumb like "once you get to four arguments, bundle them all up in an object."

Do note that it is far easier to pass a bundle of arguments in a single object in languages that have nice object literals and don't require you to declare classes or call getters, so the language itself does figure in.

Rebecca Murphey has a recent blog post which covers exactly this issue in some depth.  I think you might like it: http://blog.rebeccamurphey.com/objects-as-arguments-in-javascript-where-do-y.

Answer (score 1):

Does myFunction need to know about Object?  If so, pass Object.  Or does myFunction simply need three values that could come from anywhere?  If so then pass three values.  As a general rule, lean toward the latter choice because it gives you a more general-purpose function and fewer dependencies.  If myFunction really needs to know about Object then it should probably be a method of Object.

Answer (score 1):

The question comes down to this: do the arguments "make sense" to be a meaningfull object?
If so you might put them together into a "parameter object" However, if that Parameter Object is only used in this specific context, it makes no sense again.

Example, myMethod(int a, int b, float d); The arguments not even have proper names, so it wont make any sense at all to craft a Parameter object for it. Now conisder this, setOwner(String familyName, String firstName, Date birthday), obviously this describes a full flesh Person, so why not using a Person-Object?

Finally: your APIs become much more expressive if they mainly focus on objects that make sense in your domain, instead of passing around primitiv or simple types.

E.g. in Java UI programming I'm very often using Dimensions objects instead fo width and height as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion as a general OOP(Frank: I don't have much experience):

It depends the functionality of the method. If you want the method to manipulate only to the values of a particular kind of object, then accepting such object as an argument gives better meaning. But if you want the method to manipulate general function(not specific to any object), then passing the individual values gives a better meaning.

Answer (score 0):

When you're passing Object to a function and use its members (properties/methods) inside, you're creating a physical dependency upon that Object. Meaning that whenever you'd require to change something in Object for whatever reason, you will also need to take into account how it is used inside this function. Sometimes it is desirable and sometimes not - it depends on the context. The general rule of thumb is that the less dependencies the better. Passing explicit parameters instead of Object also better fits to a *Dependency Inversion Principle* as we don't rely on concrete implementation of Object.
That said, having many parameters to a function is not very practical, and very often a specific kind of objects are being introduced just for that purpose - containers.